# Detect when document is not at top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply a class once the document isn't at top anymore, i.e. when the user scrolls down. Could someone explain why this isn't working:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
  // Do stuff
};
```

For clarification reasons, here's the functionality I'm looking for (the appearing `border-bottom` on the header): http://doodle.com/bspuhf6cazqpwhwi

Comment: Assuming you're running that code under `$(window).scroll()` it should work fine.

Comment: You used jQuery 2.1.1, there is not i.e. supporting.
Attach migration.js (jQuery), or use lte version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.scrollY` is your friend.

```
function checkScroll() {
    if(window.scrollY > 0) {
        // add classname
    } else {
        setTimeout(checkScroll, 300) // check again after 300ms
    }
}
checkScroll()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    // Do stuff
  } else {
    // Do other stuff
  }
});
```